# Google drive document editor shows other linked apps like calendar and other google product navigation. How to hide what drop box done?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

As of now when open the sheets in Google drive it show to other linked apps like calendar and other google product navigation.

In Dropbox That menu section was hidden.

I opened edit link in iframe html tag for document. I want to hide side menu with calendar menu when click toggle button.

Is there any Google Drive API available in .NET?

[image: Iframe image]

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: That being said Check google docs api.  Its not going to give you an editor its just json it returns your going to have to make your own editor.   Some google drive files have a weblink that will open to google drive but it will only work if the user has permissons set on the file.

Comment: Yes, It returns only json. I created my own editor . I have enabled all the permission from google drive api.

I have opened google drive editor by below link with file id in drive

`var documentUrl = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/" + file.Id + "/edit";`

Comment: You are just opening the file in google drive this isnt the same as creating your own editor.  You cant control Google drive web application.

Comment: In Dropbox they are using google drive editor. They hide this option.

Comment: Have can  i achieve this? any other ways?

Comment: You do realize that dropbox and google drive are two different systems created by two different companions.  As stated in my answer you have no control over the google drive web application.

Answer (score 0):

The google drive API is just a file storage api.  It just has storage information of the files selves.  Its up to you how you display them.

You haven't created your own editor. You are simply opening the file in Google drive web application and displaying it to a user.   You have no control over the Google drive web application thats controlled by google and has nothing to do with the Google drive api other than it probably reads from it.  You cant close the menu.

If you do want to create your own editor you should check out the Google docs api this will allow you to edit documents stored in google drive.  However it also only returns json everything visual will be up to you to create.